# How do you implement a select statement in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

Can anyone please tell me how to implement select statements in VBScript, similar to switch statement in C? It would be great if you provided some examples as I'm pretty new to VBScript. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

```
Select Case foo
    Case 1
       MsgBox "1"
    Case 2, 3
       MsgBox "2 or 3"
    Case Else
       MsgBox "Something else"
End Select
```

Comment: Gary,Thanks a lot.Since i am just a beginner,got some probs with getting used to vbscripts.

Answer (score 0):

example only

```
 Select Case strMyVariable
      Case "One"     Wscript.Echo "1"
      Case "Two"     Wscript.Echo "2"
      Case "Three"   Wscript.Echo "3"
      Case Else      Wscript.Echo "Wrong"
 End Select
```

Comment: Ghostdog,I just got another doubt.Are there any break statements associated with each case??

Comment: Nope  no break in VBScript, often wondered why it exists in other languages?

Comment: @MrTelly:  Goes back to old C (pre C++) days where any small opporunity to save a few bytes in the code were considered worthwhile despite the potential spaggetti it could create.

Comment: @Maddy, in response to your questions, as MrTelly said, no breaks in case select, but you can do "break" in for loops.