# Select case number between in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

How can I make a select like the following one in Classic ASP?

```
<%
Select case aNumber
    case 1 to 2
        a="pizza"
    case 3 to 4
        a="pasta"
    case else
        a="spaghetti"
end select
%>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you implement a select statement in VBScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124474/how-do-you-implement-a-select-statement-in-vbscript)

Comment: No @Lankymart, is not.

Comment: How do you figure that? You're asking how to do a [VB.Net syntax trick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in VBScript, simple answer is it doesn't exist, what does exist is listed in the answers to that question. Does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37460988/692942) here not help?

Comment: @Lankymart asking `how can I make like` by sampling an invalid code is not a duplicate of `How do you implement` I think. I call this a workaround seek.

Comment: Look @Kul-Tigin it doesn't take 5 minutes to lookup `Select Case` syntax in VBScript, I flagged it as a possible dup because it is but still tried to provide an answer to help out the OP. As you will be aware it's already got 3 close votes, so someone disagrees with you.

Comment: @Lankymart just specified my opinion with a reason, left an answer and did not count any votes. I'm OK with if someone disagrees with me. this things happen often :)

Comment: You understand that Classic ASP uses VBScript as the default scripting engine?, if you want to use something else you call the `@language` directive or `<script language="..." runat="server">` block.

Comment: I think the key is "between". Changing the title to swap 'Classic ASP' for 'VBScript' would render the question valid, no? That specific question is _not_ asked nor answered in the linked post.

Comment: @bacar it still a dup if you change the title or not, plus would does dropping asp-classic do? It's still VBScript so it's still a dup, the fact the question doesn't mention specifically about `Case value to value` is irrelevant *(as no such syntax exists)*. To be honest whether it's a dup or not doesn't matter as answers have been left anyway and up-voted, so worse case it gets marked as a dup but still remains.

Comment: May not be ideal wording but it's clear enough from the code sample what behaviour the OP would like, and both answers seem to address that, so the fact that 'no such syntax exists' itself seems irrelevant. Are we not allowed pseudo-code in questions? Does SO now ban questions about why code does not compile because we cannot supply a compilable code sample? The question is distinctly _not_ "How do you implement a select statement in VBScript?". If you think there is a Q like "Is there a simple 'select case' syntax that works for numeric ranges" please post a link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifying ranges in `Select Case Statement` is from the days of VB6, maybe older. [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266274%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and VB.Net also supports but never implemented in VBScript, strange. So you can't.

But there's other ways to achieve similar results. A workaround like below for example :

```vb
Select Case True 'looking for True
    Case aNumber >= 1 And aNumber <= 2
        a = "pizza"
    Case aNumber >= 3 And aNumber <= 4
        a = "pasta"
    Case Else
        a = "spaghetti"
End Select
```

or by enhancing with a helper function:

```vb
Function InRange(val, min, max)
    InRange = val >= min And val <= max
End Function

Select Case True 'looking for True
    Case InRange(aNumber, 1, 2)
        a = "pizza"
    Case InRange(aNumber, 3, 4)
        a = "pasta"
    Case Else
        a = "spaghetti"
End Select
```

Comment: I've used this approach myself before.

Comment: @Lankymart I'd bet you have, instead of tens of nested `If` blocks :/

Comment: I must admit though as a quick hack approach I tend to favour `Case value, value, ...`. Obviously if you are dealing with large ranges this approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

You can't but there is a work around

```vb
<%
Dim aNumber: aNumber = 1
Dim a

Select case aNumber
Case 1, 2
  a = "pizza"
Case 3, 4
  a = "pasta"
Case Else
  a = "spaghetti"
End Select

Call Response.Write(a)
%>
```

Output:

```
pizza
```

This may look like above but it isn't working the same way, take for example if we wanted to change `1 to 2` to `1 to 3` for the first `Case`;

```vb
<%
Dim aNumber: aNumber = 2
Dim a

Select case aNumber
Case 1, 3
  a = "pizza"
Case 4
  a = "pasta"
Case Else
  a = "spaghetti"
End Select

Call Response.Write(a)
%>
```

Output:

```
spaghetti
```

We don't get `pizza` because the `Case` has to include all the options, it doesn't work on a range basis, so the following modification is needed for it to work;

```vb
Case 1, 2, 3
```

Output:

```
pizza
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [MSDN - Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [How do you implement a select statement in VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124490/692942)
- [Condition in Case of Select/Case statement in classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15231204/692942) *(not the clearest explanation)*

Comment: Problem is, what if `aNumber` equals 2.312423?

Comment: @Martha if it's dealing with decimals then this obviously is no good and Kul-Tigin's approach would be better, but equally it wouldn't work if you passed a date range but hey I didn't realise OP was going that deep. That's the problem with mediocre questions, the are open to interpretation due to lacklustre effort the OP has put into it. To be honest it's very frustrating.